# Java, square a number

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, multiplication

I am working on a basic assignment for school, namely to square a number.

And, I have written the following code;

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Write a number: ");
String mataintal = scan.next();
int nr = Integer.parseInt(mataintal);
String.out.println = mataintal * mataintal;
```

I am attempting to multiply the number I read with my `Scanner`, is there some easy way I can do that? And display the square of that number?

Comment: `String.out.println` is a method. Also you probably want `System.out.println`.

Comment: No, it's not. But System.out.println() is one.

Comment: Note that Scanner has a nextInt() method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Call the **method** `println` from `System.out` (not `String.out` which doesn't exist), you don't assign a value to it. And you multiply the `int` you parsed.

```
String.out.println = mataintal * mataintal;
```

should be

```
System.out.println(nr * nr);
```

Answer (score 1):

this  makes no sense>

String.out.println = mataintal * mataintal;

you print using

```
System.out.println();
```

on the other hand, **mataintal** is a String, you need instead **nr** which is the result of parsing that string into an integer

your final line must be like:

**System.out.println(nr * nr);**

Comment: Ty, I just made a typeo on the String.out.println() part. Ty for the explanation for the parsing string into an integer.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `double pow(double base, double exponent)` as well.

Example:

```
System.out.println(Math.pow(mataintal, 2);
```

Comment: as you mentioned, `pow` takes two doubles, but `mataintal` is a `String` in this example. Because `String`s are not automatically casted to doubles either, this does not really solve his problem...

Comment: Ohh I missed it..
I think then correct approach here is to convert String to double using double dblNum = Double.parseDouble(String mataintal),  

then use the 
Math.pow(dblNum, 2);